# How to POST/PATCH user model with django restful api

Tags: django, rest, api

I have a django oscar shop and expanded my user model with a treatment field:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
treatment = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

Now I want to expand the django oscar api in order to post or patch a user (I want to change "treatment").

If I go to http://localhost:8000/api/users/ and try to post a new one, I just get this error:

```
TypeError at /api/users/
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DeferredAttribute'
```

Has anyone an idea how to handle this?

views.py:

```
class UserList(basic.UserList):
    queryset = User.objects.all()     
    serializer_class = CreateUserSerializer

        def post(self, request, format=None):         
    v_ser = self.serializer_class( data=request.data, context={'request': request}) 
    if v_ser.is_valid():            
        ser = self.serializer_class( User, context={'request': request}) 
        return Response(ser.data)

return Response(v_ser.errors, status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
```

serializers.py:

```
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:         
        model = User         
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'treatment')     

    email = serializers.EmailField()    
    treatment = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, required=True)

def validate(self, attrs):

    #oscar expects this always to be uppercase.
    attrs['treatment'] = attrs['treatment'].upper()
    request = self.context.get('request') 
    return attrs



def create(self, validated_data): 
    return User.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: where do you get that error (show us full stack trace)? and when you use `User` in your view and serialiser, where do you import it from?

Comment: And please format your code correctly (indentation-wise) so we can follow the flow.